# Resolving Database Stored XSS issues from Checkmarx

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, checkmarx

Here I am getting Error at the `List<Data> dataList = jdbcTemplate.query` location.

Checkmarx says:

> AppServices/src/main/java/com/mbusa/app/dao/impl/AppRequestDAOImpl.java
>   gets data from the database, for the query element. This element’s
>   value then flows through the code without being properly filtered or
>   encoded and is eventually displayed to the user in method
>   getRequestDetail at line 117 of
>   AppWeb/src/main/java/com/mbusa/app/controllers/AppRequestController.java.
>   This may enable a Stored Cross-Site-Scripting attack.

```
List<Data> dataList = jdbcTemplate.query(new PreparedStatementCreator() {

                @Override
                public PreparedStatement createPreparedStatement(Connection conn) throws SQLException {
                    PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(fSQL);
                    int index = 1;
                    for(Object param: effParams) {
                        pstmt.setString(index, (String) param);
                        index++;
                    }
                    return pstmt;
                }
            }, new RequestMapper());

public class RequestMapper implements RowMapper<Data> {

    @Override
    public Data mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
        Data data = new Data();
        data.setName(rs.getString("name"));
        return data ;
    }


}
```

I have added `PreparedStatement` here to resolve this issue and also tried adding `HtmlUtil.htmlEscape` upon output data, but still could not resolve this issue.

Can anyone help with this issue?

Comment: It is hard to answer by the code you supplied. Can you add the entire code flow (From input to DB) to the question?

Comment: Problem is that a "Store XSS". You're data is not validate/sanitized for Cx. HTML Encoding is perhaps not sufficient for this too. Have a look at a really good encoder (OWASP JAva Encoder is a good solution). If you encode ALL your output and validate input, this  finding is a False Positive

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @AnatolyLibman  - Any luck with solution ?